# How can i get internet accessibility On in my application even during phone is idle?

Tags: android, http, gps, location, fuse

I am working on a project, where user's location is being tracked continuously. I am using fuse location api for the same. I have noticed that I am getting location updates regularly, but Problem is with sending this location to server. When phone is idle, while sending location using below code, It will show "java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "myurl": No address associated with hostname"

I am using this code to send location to server:

```
try {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpParams httpParameters = httpclient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
        if (activity == null)
            callAPI(uri, httpclient);
        else if (commonMethods.knowInternetOn(activity)) {
            callAPI(uri, httpclient);
        } else {
            commonMethods.showInternetAlert(activity);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



private void callAPI(String[] uri, HttpClient httpclient) {

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            responseString = out.toString();
            out.close();
        } else {
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            if (activity != null) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Toast.makeText(activity, "Server Error!",
                        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        responseString = null;
                    }
                });
            }
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException ue) {
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    commonMethods.displayToastAboveButton(activity, "Server Not Found!");
                    responseString = null;
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        responseString = null;
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException se) {
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    commonMethods.displayToastAboveButton(activity, "Internet Problem!");
                    responseString = null;
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseString = null;
    }

}
```

My question is:
How can i get INTERNET ACCESS in my application even during phone is idle ?

Note: When i press power button, and phone is awake again, all is working perfect, i.e. not getting any Unknown host exception.

Comment: you can use service if you want some continue task